# WordPress - Modifying the MediaFlux theme

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the **MediaFlux** theme from Mojo-Themes on my website at [www.sjsueconomics.org](http://www.sjsueconomics.org). Here are my questions:

1. As you can see on the website, the *blue menu* at the very top of the page currently displays **Page Titles**. I want to display **External Links** there instead. How do I modify the code to do it?
2. The main menu (red text below the logo) currently displays **Categories**. Without changing the style or appearance, I want to display the **Page Titles** instead. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the theme supports custom menus, there ought to be a Menus page in the admin, under Appearances probably, or perhaps Settings. Go there, then create a menu with the pages or categories you want, then tell the theme to use the menu you created instead of the default. If the theme doesn't have such a feature, you'll need a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

1. The company you paid for the theme provides support, not a community which has no access to this product.
2. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com ; customizing a paid theme while providing no code (and having no right to provide any code) is not an appropriate subject for a StackOverflow question

Comment: It turns out that the company I paid for the theme (mojo-themes) did not create the theme. They only sell the themes. They directed me to post my question on a forum where I did not receive a response, hence trying here, in the hope that someone familiar with the theme would know how to fix it.

Comment: What are the chances that out of the tens of thousands of themes for WP, someone who has paid for that one will be on SO, and watching the wordpress tag, and is a programmer, and wants to provide free customization for someone else's paid theme?

Comment: (1) I tried to add the tag MediaFlux, but SO does not allow me to because I'm a newbie. (2) Freelance developers modify the themes for customers who purchased them, and hopefully several freelance developers can be found here. (3) From what I understand, a slight modification in the code will switch the content displayed. (4) If someone knew how to do it, but would do it for a reasonable fee, I would pay. But they should ask. :-)

Comment: I'm available(see my answer below) :) but without looking at the theme itself, no way to tell if it's a 'slight' modification.

Comment: @yitwail Your advice worked like a charm! Thanks very much! But in case I need to hire your services in the future, how do I contact you? (I am moving nearly two dozen of the web assets that I manage to WordPress, and I am sure I will need help.)

Comment: I'm glad I was of assistance. I notice you have a contact form. If that works, I can use it to send contact info.